# SwiftUI DatePicker and Date wrong timezone, not using the local one

Tags: swiftui

I am implementing a `DatePicker` in `SwiftUI`.

```
@State var dateTime = Date()
DatePicker("Date and time, selection: $dateTime)
```

However, when I select a date & time there and try to print the result I get a different time.

```
print(self.dateTime.description(with: .current))
print(self.dateTime)
```

The idea is that if I select 10:28 PM, the first line with `.current` returns the selected value, but as a String and the second one returns a completely different value, usually with some hours added which I think it takes by default UTC+0 or something, I am now in GMT+3.

I think I have read a lot of answers in the past hour but nothing exactly about this. Any idea is much appreciated.

Comment: `Date` is always in UTC, use calendar to have it in some zone or formatter.

Comment: What is the *correct* time you want to display? UTC or local?

Comment: @pawello2222 local

Comment: But `DatePicker` already displays the Date in the local time zone and `print(self.dateTime.description(with: .current))` will print the local time as well. Where is the issue?